# JPA entities relationship and criteria builder for joined column

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

My Application has these entites:

```
@Entity
public class proposal implements Serializable {

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "F1PRP")        
private Long proposalCode;

//more fields...
}

@Entity
public class branch implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
protected branchPK branchpk;

//more fields..
}

@Embeddable
public class branchPK implements Serializable {

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "F2PRP")
private long proposalCode;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "F2BRN")
private short proposalBranch;
}
```

Each `proposal` have a primary key (`proposalCode`) , and each proposal can have multiple branch values.
I'm not sure how to build the relationships between them so that I will be able to create a criteria builder for this joined column.

My question is what relationships should be between those enteties, and how do i build the criteria builder with join? 
The user will give me a value of `proposalBranch` , and I need to show only the `proposal`'s that have this  proposalBranch inside of them.

How do I do that?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the entities you posted, there is no relationship between the proposalCode in the proposal entity and the one that is part of the branch entity, so I assume that they must be the same.

About the relationship you said that each proposal can have multiple branch values, so that is mapped as a @OneToMany relationship from proposal to branch:

```
@Entity
public class proposal
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "F1PRP")        
    private Long proposalCode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="proposal")
    private List<branch> branches;
}

@Entity
public class branch
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "F2BRN")
    private short proposalBranch;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="F2PRP")
    private proposal proposal;
}
```

With that setup, the criteria query should be easy to build having a "Root" as proposal and invoking "join" on branch. [This is a good explanation of how Criteria API works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/).